# Property "controls" not working in InputNumber antd

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd

Here I use InputNumber from ANTD, if you look at the documentation there is a property called '**controls**', but if you look at Image1 (that is my project) the property "**controls**" doesn't work.
but when i try it in codesandbox (in the Image2) it works, is there something wrong i did? Please help. thank you

Image1
[Image1 in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyiVN.png)

Image2 [Image2 in CodeSandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K54g1.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i share the code in my image

Comment: just to confirm that the `controls` property indeed appears to have no effect on the rendering of th`InputNumber` component (tested with `antd 4.8.2`)